# How can I highlight a table row based on a cell click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a Bootstrap Table. If the user clicks on a specific cell (Delete), I would like to highlight the row red. I am using the `click-cell.bs.table`, but nothing happens when I click on a cell.

```
$table.on("click-cell.bs.table", function (field, value, row, $element) {
   if (field == 'Delete') {
        $element.parent().toggleClass('bg_delete');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46eaytfn/

Comment: this should fix it a bit more, just haven't fixed teh add class part

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Did you mean to include a JSFiddle link?

Comment: yes sorry here it is http://jsfiddle.net/46eaytfn/1/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks. I realized I didn't assign the name using Jquery. I took what you did a little further, but the highlighting doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/46eaytfn/3/ Also I don't know why the field has quotes around it so it's like `''Delete"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needs events as its first parameter.

And two minor issues: 1) Correct `$table` to `$('#table')` and 2) Remove `parent` function.

Here is the solution:

```
$('#table').on("click-cell.bs.table", function (e, field, value, row, $element) {

if (field === 'Delete') {
        $element.toggleClass('bg_delete');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great, but I wuld like to highlight the whole row, not just the cell. I tried `$element.parent().toggleClass('bg_delete');`, but that seems inconsistent and the highlight disappears on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/4ek2znw3/

Comment: `click-cell.bs.table` for `<td>` and `click-row.bs.table` for `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a little bit of CSS. Please have a look.

see sample code below 
http://jsfiddle.net/4ek2znw3/

```
#table .bg_delete td {
   background-color: #ff0000 !important;
   opacity: 0.5  !important;
}
```